# BindingAdapter I created in my library module is not accessbiel from any app module after I distributed the library via gradle

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I recently created a library and in that I made a BindingAdapter which is somehow like below (simply decorating a text on TextView).

```
@BindingAdapter({"decorateText"})
public static void decorateText(final View view, String text) {
    ((TextView)view).setText("<<<" + text + ">>>");
}
```

This BindingAdapter is accessible from the app module in the same Android Studio project like below

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:decorateText="@{`Buy Now`}"/>
```

But after I distributed the library through jcenter, and imported the library from a different app project via gradle, I couldn't use `"app:decorateText"` tag.

I got below error.

```
No resource identifier found for attribute ‘decorateText' in package 'com.goldrushcomputing.myapplication'
```

I could call public methods of this library from the app, so the library looks properly imported to the project.

Is there any trick to make BindingAdapter in a library accessible from app modules, or is it not possible ?

Comment: Given that data binding uses Binding Adapters from a module, I think it should work.  Are you distributing the aar file or just the jar?

Comment: Hi, it is aar file distributed via jcenter maven repository.

Comment: @GeorgeMount
 
Stupid me : ( I had forgotten to add dataBinding {enabled = true} in the test app's gradle. Now it works! 
Anyway your confirmation helped.
I read your blog about RecyclerView+DataBinding which was really good. 
Thank you for introducing such a great technology to us.

Comment: @TakamitsuMizutori thanks I had exactly the same problem !

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you added

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

to your library module's `.gradle` file.